# C lexer: token concatenation of unterminated string literals

Tags: c, compilation, c-preprocessor

Consider the following c code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRE(a) " ## a

int main() {
    printf("%s\n", PRE("));
    return 0;
}
```

If we adhere strictly to the tokenization rules of c99, I would expect it to break up as:

```
...
[#] [define] [PRE] [(] [a] [)] ["]* [##] [a]
...
[printf] [(] ["%s\n"] [,] [PRE] [(] ["]* [)] [)] [;]
...
```

* A single non-whitespace character that does not match any `preprocessing-token` pattern

And thus, after running preprocessing directives, the printf line should become:

```c
printf("%s\n", "");
```

And parse normally. But instead, **it throws an error** when compiled with gcc, even when using the flags `-std=c99 -pedantic`. What am I missing?

Comment: `A single non-whitespace character that does not match any preprocessing-token pattern` but why? a `string-literal` is a preprocessing token. And a `string-literal` starts with a `"`. And `If a ' or a " character matches the last category,`...(ie. does not match a string-literal)...`the behavior is undefined.` from [C11 6.4p3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4p3)

Comment: Missed that sentence. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [C11 6.4. Lexical elements](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4):

> ```
>       preprocessing-token:
>              header-name
>              identifier
>              pp-number
>              character-constant
>              string-literal
>              punctuator
>              each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above
> ```
>
> 3 [...] The categories of preprocessing tokens are: header names,
> identifiers, preprocessing numbers, character constants, string
> literals, punctuators, and single non-white-space characters that do
> not lexically match the other preprocessing token categories.69) **If a
> ' or a " character matches the last category, the behavior is
> undefined.** [...]

So if `"` is not part of a string-literal, but is a non-white-space character, the behavior is undefined. I do not know why it's undefined and not a hard error - I think it's to allow compilers to parse multiline string literals.

> it throws an error

[But on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dGP8b4T9c):

```
<source>:3:16: warning: missing terminating " character
    3 | #define PRE(a) " ## a
      |                ^
<source>:6:24: warning: missing terminating " character
    6 |     printf("%s\n", PRE("));
      |                        ^
<source>:8: error: unterminated argument list invoking macro "PRE"
    8 | }
      | 
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:6:20: error: 'PRE' was not declared in this scope
    6 |     printf("%s\n", PRE("));
      |                    ^~~
<source>:6:20: error: expected '}' at end of input
<source>:5:12: note: to match this '{'
    5 | int main() {
      |            ^
```

it throws an error **not** on `#define PRE` line (it could), but on `PRE(")` line. Tokens are recognized before macro substitutions ([phase 3 vs phase 4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2)), so whatever you do you can't like "create" new lexical string literals as a result of macro substitution by for example gluing two macros or like you want to do. Note that `-pedantic` will not change the warning into error - `-pedantic` throws errors where standard tells to throw error, but the standard tells the behavior is undefined, so no error is needed there.